# PHP array of arrays to store mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
<?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chemistry_data_base', 'root', '');
    $a1 = array();
    //to...
    $a118 = array();
    $element = array("a1" => $a1, $a2, .......,$a118);

    $counter = 1;

    while ($counter != 119)
    {
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT Atomic_Number, Element_Mass, Element_Group, Element_Period, Chemical_Symbol, Element_Name, Element_State, Metal_Type, Element_Configuration, Oxidation_State, Melting_Point, Boiling_Point, Ionization_Energy, Electron_Affinity_1, Electron_Affinity_2, Electronegativity, Atomic_Radius FROM periodic_table WHERE Atomic_Number = ?");
        $statement->execute(array($counter));   
        $element[$counter] = $statement->fetch();
        ?>
        <header> <?php echo $element[$counter["Element_Name"]]; ?> </header>
        <?php
        $counter++;
    }
```

At the start of the page, I want to assign each variable ($a1 - $a118) with all of the relevant information. I am aware that I could just solve this by "manually" interfacing with the db for each variable to get the relevant information, but I wanted to know if there is a way of doing it in a neater and more structured way. The idea is that I could later as in the example just call on each elements info via

```
$element[$counter["Element_property_I_want"]]
```

Thank you The_Moth

**Possible Solution by JensV:**

I have updated the code to

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chemistry_data_base', 'root', '');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT Atomic_Number, Element_Mass, Element_Group, Element_Period, Chemical_Symbol, Element_Name, Element_State, Metal_Type, Element_Configuration, Oxidation_State, Melting_Point, Boiling_Point, Ionization_Energy, Electron_Affinity_1, Electron_Affinity_2, Electronegativity, Atomic_Radius FROM periodic_table WHERE Atomic_Number BETWEEN 1 AND 118');

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$indexedData = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
  $indexedData[$row['Atomic_Number']] = $row;
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);

// Access your array by the AtomicNumber
echo $indexedData[42]['Atomic_Number'];

?>
    <header> <?php echo $indexedData[42]["Atomic_Number"]; ?> </header>
```

The new error that I'm getting is:

array(0) {
}

Notice:  Undefined offset: 42 in C:\xampp\htdocs\data_element\periodic_table.php on line 228

Notice:  Undefined offset: 42 in C:\xampp\htdocs\data_element\periodic_table.php on line 231

: Line 228 and 231 are both the echo lines.

It seams to me after some experimenting and so, that the array seems to be empty and isn't getting filled, but I could very well be wrong.

Comment: So you are creating 118 arrays (`$a1-$a118`), pushing them in yet another array, making 118 select statements to push the result into yet another 118-long array, only to echo te result? Seems a bit overdone.

Comment: if you are getting new errors, make a new question, don't ask two questions at the same time

Comment: Looks like there isn't any data in the table matching the condition

Comment: @JensV yeah the problem seems to be in assigning a value to the array, as after further testing the retrieval seems to work fine. Currently I am testing if it might be possible with variable variables, but as arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an entry for every empty space that you want to fill with data:

```
while ($counter < 119)
{
    $a[$counter] = $counter;
    $counter++;
}
$counter = 1;
```

Select your data from your MySQL data base and insert it into the array inside of the array:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT xyz FROM db WHERE xyz = ?");
while ($counter < 119)
{
    $statement->execute(array($counter));   
    ${$a[$counter]}[1] = $statement->fetch();
    $counter++;
}
```

This is how you call your array:

```
var_dump( ${$a[1]}[1]. "<br>");
```

**WARNING!**

This is extremely finicky and very difficult to set up properly. I wouldn't ever advise doing it this way as just about every other way is easier. If you think this is the only way of solving your problem you are wrong. There are other ways that are a lot uglier and a lot more code, but so much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just fetch all the data at once (especially since mysql queries are expensive and it should be avoided to iterate over the same query where possible).

Just do something similar to this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT f1,f2,f3, etc... FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 133');

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now all your data is in `$data` and can be accessed with `$data[42]['f2']`

> Be aware that the `$data` array is 0-indexed! So `$data[5]['id']` will probably be `6`

---

#### Reindexing the data

Since you want the array to be indexed by the Atomic number you would need to reindex the array. Simplest way to do that is to just create a new array with the correct indices:

```
// ... fetch the data into $data
$indexedData = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
  $indexedData[$row['AtomicNumber']] = $row;
}

// Access your array by the AtomicNumber
echo $indexedData[42]['someKey'];
```

Also to help while debugging use `var_dump` or `print_r` and if you're viewing it in a webbrowser you can add a `<pre>` tag for nice formatting. For example:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data); // or var_dump($indexedData);
```

Comment: thx I'll try that, that sound like that could be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @The_Moth if it helped an upvote and accept would be appreciated

Comment: yeah. I'm still working on it as there still are some problems I'm having with it

Comment: FETCH_ASSOC seems to need () after it to run, but when I change it to FETCH_ASSOC() It gives me a different error, so I'm reading through the FETCH_ASSOC manuals to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: What kind of error are you receiving? The `()` is not needed there as `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` is a constant. Perhaps check your sql statement for any errors.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait, had a lot going on. The error that I'm getting is: Notice: Undefined offset: 42 in C:\xampp\htdocs\data_element\periodic_table.php on line 220

Comment: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT Atomic_Number, Element_Mass, Element_Group, Element_Period, Chemical_Symbol, Element_Name, Element_State, Metal_Type, Element_Configuration, Oxidation_State, Melting_Point, Boiling_Point, Ionization_Energy, Electron_Affinity_1, Electron_Affinity_2, Electronegativity, Atomic_Radius FROM periodic_table WHERE Atomic_Number BETWEEN 1 AND 118');

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
 <header> <?php echo $data[42]["Atomic_Number"]; ?> </header>` is the code that is spitting out the error. The part with the echo is line 220.

Comment: @The_Moth I've amended my answer, see if it helps. If you have new code, rather edit your answer than writing a comment. If you have a new separate problem, create a new question.

Comment: Thx for your continued help. But I'm still getting the same or similar errors. I'm not sure if there is just a really mean problem or I am just missing something really obvious.